# csh: Using -d as an argument and not test

Tags: csh

I know that `-d /path/to/dir` can be used to `test` command for checking a directory. Then:

```
if ( $argv[1] == "-d" )
```

does not work because of that.

However, I need to be able to pass `-d` as an argument to my script. How can I disable the special property of `-d` so I can pass it as an argument?

Comment: what makes you think that `-d` doesn't work as an argument?  The fact that `test` or `[` use it doesn't mean it can't be used by anything else.

Comment: This depends largely on how your script is parsing arguments; can you [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/238361/edit) your post to show a concise, repeatable example of the code?

Comment: [Also posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318625/csh-using-d-as-argument)

Answer (score 4):

Just using double quote `"$var"` or `:q` operator `$var:q`.

---

In `csh` variants, when variable is substituted without *double quote*, its result will be expanded as command or file name substituted (That's also true in POSIX shell, forgetting the double quote make your script [chocked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/38906) and lead to many [security implications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906)). So:

```
if ( "$argv[1]" == "-d" ) echo 1
```

will work. Even better to use `:q` operator to work with newline:

```
if ( $argv[1]:q == "-d" ) echo 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`-d` doesn't have any special properties, so there's nothing to disable.

As cuonglm mentioned the error you are seeing is due to improper quoting of the `$argv[1]` variable, not because of some imaginary special property of `-d`.  Here's proof:

```
$ csh 
% if ( "-d" == "-d" ) echo true
true
% if ( -d == "-d" ) echo true
if: Missing file name.
```

Comment: Using ./script -d to launch the script prints "If: missing file name" because it wants to test for a directory.

Comment: That would be due to a coding error in your script, not because of some imaginary special property of `-d`.  cuonglm explains what you did wrong - you didn't use double-quotes around the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a dummy character before the statement. Like so:

```
if ( X$argv[1] == "X-d" ).
```

Comment: Using X or any other letter to avoid properly quoting your variables is extremely bad practice.  It is a bug waiting to happen.